# ModuleBuildError, how to configure webpack.config.dev.js to find bower_components?

Tags: reactjs, bower

I am trying to use bower with create-react-app.

In my webpack.config.dev.js I have added bower_components so that webpack should look for them like it looks for node_modules:

```js
resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['bower_components','node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
```

and my file structure is organized as:

|bower_components

|config

|-> jest

|-> env.js

|-> paths.js

|-> polyfills.js

|-> webpack.config.dev.js

|-> webpack.config.prod.js

|-> webpackDevServer.config.js

|node_modules

|public

|scripts

|src

|.bowerrc

|.gitignore

|bower.json

|package-lock.json

|postcss.config.js

|README.md

|yarn.lock

The error I'm getting is: 
./src/index.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
@import "px-colors-design/_settings.colors.scss";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: px-colors-design/_settings.colors.scss.
Parent style sheet: stdin
      in /Users//app-react-test/src/index.scss (line 2, column 1)

and if I change the import manually to @import "bower_components/px_colors_design/_settings.colors.scss" it works. How do I configure my project to search for bower_components automatically though?